# Using Multithreading for Inference in Tensorflow with OpenCV

Tags: multithreading, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, inference

I know using Multithreading is usefull training a DNN with Tensorflow.

But does it make any sense to use it for inference? For example if you are using Googles Object Detection API for realtime object detection in video streams? 
And if Yes, how is it implemented?

I created a github repo (https://github.com/GustavZ/realtime_object_detection) that allows easy Real Time Object Detection but i am not satisfied with the generated FPS, So i thougth about using Multithreading to speed it up.

Has anybody Experience with this or could help me implement it in my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 21 12:01:40 2017
@author: GustavZ
"""
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2


# Protobuf Compilation (once necessary)
os.system('protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.')

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from stuff.helper import FPS2

# Define Video Input
# Must be OpenCV readable
# 0 = Default Camera
video_input = 0
width = 640
height = 480
fps_interval = 3

# Model preparation
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = 'models/' + MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
LABEL_MAP = 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'object_detection/data/' + LABEL_MAP
NUM_CLASSES = 90

# Download Model    
if not os.path.isfile(PATH_TO_CKPT):
    print('Model not found. Downloading it now.')
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
    for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
      if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
        tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
    os.remove('../' + MODEL_FILE)
else:
    print('Model found. Proceed.')

# Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# Loading label map
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Start Video Stream
video_stream = cv2.VideoCapture(video_input)
video_stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
video_stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

# Detection
print ("Press 'q' to Exit")
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess: # config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    # fps calculation
    fps = FPS2(fps_interval).start()
    while video_stream.isOpened():
      ret_val,image_np = video_stream.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      cv2.imshow('object_detection', image_np)
      # Exit Option
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
      fps.update()

# End everything
video_stream.release()     
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
fps.stop()
print('[INFO] elapsed time (total): {:.2f}'.format(fps.elapsed()))
print('[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}'.format(fps.fps()))
```

Comment: I would not expect calling `sess.run()` from multiple threads to improve your throughput. TensorFlow's core runtime is already heavily multi-threaded. Your Python code simply starts the execution. One thing that can improve your throughput is to batch many images together and invoke sess.run() once. I don't know much about the other calls you are making (e.g. `video_stream.read()`) to speculate if multi-threading can help with them.

Comment: You probably can't speed up the calls to sess.run() with multithreading. I don't know if you can for video_stream.read(), I'm not familiar with it either. But you can have one process reading the video stream, and another one doing the inferences, so that none of these has to wait for the other one to finish. This can only be interesting if the two operations take roughly the same time, which is probably not the case as is (reading images from the stream should be much faster), but could become the case with a bigger batch size..

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense only if you run it on a device where your computing capacities are limited.
Basically what you would do is to run in different threads the image processing and the inference.
The result would be a smooth video display, and your inference would lag behind without impacting your display framerate.
You can see on [this file](https://github.com/vincentteyssier/emotion-detection-raspberry/blob/master/emotion_detection_v2_multithread.py) an example (just a draft, not tested yet) about how the multi threading would look like.

I am loading my model and starting my session, then looping over the video captured, feeding my prediction queue if I have capacities to infer it.